# just made a new android application, but am getting all sorts of errors

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello I have just started making an android application on my computer I have done this before on my laptop and the code is exactly the same. The only difference is it will not run. Even if I were to create a brand new application the same problem persists. I get a error that says "R cannot be resolved to a type", as well as this error "res\menu\interface.xml:0: error: invalid symbol: 'interface'" which  I dont quite understand here is the code for the brand new class that I have created. As well as the xml that the class is pointing to.

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Interface extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_interface);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.x
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have read somewhere that i need to delete the import R well as good as it sounds this does not work this is the only import that it will allow me to import for setContentView();. Here is the XML.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.lawnfinder.Interface" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As far as I know, `R` class will be generated in the package name of your application defined in manifest XML. So, it shouldn't be `android.R` but `<your package name>.R` I guess.

Comment: Yes, `R` is a generated class. `android.R` will refer to system stuff so delete that import.

Comment: Why not just have AS auto import whatever you need on the fly? I am using setContentView but dont have any imports named android.R.

Comment: I am using eclipse that is the only import that it will auto import

Comment: I had the same problem on my laptop, but i have no idea how i fixed it

Comment: nothing to do with anything you guys are saying though

Comment: Use android studio. it really much better

Comment: I still need an answer as to why this is not randomly working

Answer (score 0):

Create a new application and extend the main class with ActionBarActivity and one main thing DO NOT CREATE A SAME NAME PROJECT AGAIN THIS IS WHY U R GETTING R PEOBLEM CREATE UNIQUE NAME PROJECT because this confuses the application where does R belongs too. for me it imports

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

only no need to import R class and also enable auto importer for projects. and try not opening two or more same name projects at same time.